# Simple awk wrapper function or alias

Tags: shell, awk

I had seen someone use a bash alias or function based on awk, which I liked for its simplicity, but can't remember how to implement it (in bash).

Lets say you have a large formatted file, from which you need to pick say 3, 4, 7th column.

For this you can do:

```
cat bigfile.txt | awk '{print $3, $4, $7}' |less
```

I need an alias (or function) pawk, which I can use it as:

```
cat bigfile.txt | pawk 3,4,7 | less
```

to get the same effect. Number of columns can be arbitrary and may include NF. I tried couple of things to implement this but can't figure out how to pass arbitrary number of variables to awk.

Comment: Are you sure it was an alias and not a function? I don't think you can pass multiple argument to aliases.

Comment: I am not sure, but if it was a function it was quite small as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function like so:

```
function pawk(){
  awkString="{print "

  for var in "$@"
  do
    awkString+=" \$$var"
  done

  awkString+=" }"

  awk "$awkString"
}
```

Example:

```
cat bigfile.txt | pawk 3 4 7 | less
```

Comment: If the output fields indeed need no separator between them, this can be reduced to `function pawk() { awk "{print ${*/#/\$}}"; }`, to make it quite small, as the question owner wishes. (Note, this is Bash-only solution. But anyway @Nobe4's function syntax is already a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would probably have been a function, not an alias. With that in mind, try this:

```
pawk(){
    fields="$(sed -E 's/(^|,)/ \1\$/g'<<<"$1")"
    shift
    awk "{print $fields}" "$@"
}
```

Then you can run it as:

```
pawk 3,4,7 bigfile.txt | less
```

Or

```
cat bigfile | pawk 3,4,7 | less
```

Or even

```
pawk 3,4,7 * | less
```

The trick is adding a `$` before each comma and at the beginning of the first argument given to the function (so `1,2,3` becomes `$1,$2,$3`) and and saving the resulting string in a shell variable. You then run `awk` in double quotes so that the `$fields` variable is expanded and `awk` treats it as the firlds it should print.

The `sed -E` should be pretty portable but, the herestring (`<<<"$1"`) less so. For a fully portable version, use this:

```
pawk(){
    fields="$(printf '$%s' $(echo 1,2,3 | sed 's/,/,\$/g'))"
    shift
    awk "{print $fields}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: +1.  and if you have `shift` after processing `"$1"` then you can use `"$@"` instead of just `"$2"`.